# One to One relation between tables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Just started my first project in ROR and i'm facing a problem with build a relation between table.
As a noob i search a lot around the web, try plenty of stuff but can't figure out how to get this working.
Here's my issue: I built a User table for the login function - made with devise, now i want to build another table UserMeta to carry all the profile info of my users.

Here is the code of what i did:

*app/models/user.rb*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  attr_accessible :email, :encrypted_password

  has_one :user_meta
end
```

*app/models/user_meta.rb*

```
class UserMeta < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :admin, :birthday, :company, :first_name, :job, :last_name, :phone, :rfid, :statut, :website, :user_id

  belongs_to :users
end

class User
  has_one :user_meta
end
```

*app/controllers/user_controllers.rb*

```
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @meta = UserMeta.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end
```

app/views/users/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@meta) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :phone %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :phone %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

It returns :

```
undefined method `meta_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x000001016f3f18>:0x00000100e9f6f0>
```

I know there is one or many mistake, what the best way to do this ? Some help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Your `user_meta.rb` file redefines `User`?

Comment: Yep, i don't need it ? Well, i try without and it still an error, looks like the views can't understand what is the meta...

Comment: @x4vier I would recommend you take some time and read the Rails Associations Guide, is very comprehensible. Link: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: `has_one :user_meta`, no?

Comment: your class name should be `UserMeta` not `Meta` and `belongs_to :user` not `users`

Comment: Oh sorry guys, i edit the question

Comment: If you want to create `user_meta` with `user` why don't you just add extra columns in `user` table. And you can't submit two forms at a time.

Comment: @codeit : Because the table are from an old project i want to rewrite in Ruby. I don't really want to change all the data schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change to like this:

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :encrypted_password

  has_one :user_meta
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_meta
end
```

**app/models/user_meta.rb**

```
class UserMeta < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :admin, :birthday, :company, :first_name, :job, :last_name, :phone, :rfid, :statut, :website, :user_id

  belongs_to :user
end
```

**app/controllers/user_controllers.rb**

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.build_meta_user

   respond_to do |format|
     format.html
     format.json { render json: @user }
   end
end
```

**app/views/users/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => {:action => 'create'} do |f| %>
  <!-- User related fields -->
  <%= f.fields_for :user_meta do |meta_f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= meta_f.label :phone %><br />
      <%= meta_f.text_field :phone %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in User model.

Comment: @codeit.. you seems to be in hurry.. cool down.. :P Add the `attr_accessible` too.. ;)

Comment: hum, look like the 2nd loop in the view don't works, it don't display the form...only the title & the submit button

Comment: @x4vier you mean text field for phone is not displaying??

Comment: @x4vier Sorry, I missed `=`. Edited the answer. Check now.

Answer (score 1):

- In Rails it's best to name your classes the same as your filenames. So app/models/user_meta.rb should be `class UserMeta < ActiveRecord::Base`.
- There's no need to re-open the User-class in app/models/user_meta.rb. He'll know about app/models/user.rb already.
- Change your `belongs_to :users` to `belongs_to :user`
- In app/models/user.rb you can drop the 2nd `attr_accessible :email`.

Comment: Ok, now i can get the meta info in my view ! Thx. But it seels i still get some bugs into the form :)